# уменьшение изображения при помощи Pillow "на ходу" из url

Tags: python, файлы, изображения, request, pillow

прошу подсказки у почтенной публики.

При помощи библиотеки Pillow я написал простейший скрипт для уменьшения чрезмерно большого изображения:

```
from PIL import Image
from time import time


def image_reduction(src):
    '''function reduces the size of the image
    takes a path to a file and overwrites it'''
    img = Image.open(src)
    img.thumbnail(size=(1920, 1080))
    img.save(src)
```

где src - путь к файлу на жестком диске

функция получает файл изображения и уменьшает его, после чего перезаписывает

Но функция берет файл только с жесткого диска... а бы хотел что бы изображение не записывалось предварительно на жесткий диск, а уменьшалось "на лету", сразу из полученной ссылки.

Я пробовал получать изображение из ссылки при помощи модуля requests:

```
import requests

url = 'ссылка на изображение'
req = requests.get(url).content
```

но модуль pillow отказывается работать с полученным таким путем файлом...

Comment: Оборачивайте в BytesIO из стандартного модуля io: `pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))`

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало! Жаль, что  сам не догадался :(